# GolangのWebsocketでクライアントが送信したデータが他のクライアントに反映されない

Tags: javascript, go, websocket

GolangでWebsocketをつかって写真を共有するWeb Applicationを作っています。

あるクライアントが写真を投稿すると、すぐに、ほかのクライアントに表示されている写真がそれに更新されるようにしたいです。
そのために`*websocket.Conn`を`ws_array`という配列に入れ、データをSendするときはforで配列から取り出してデータを送信しています。

ある写真が投稿されたら、ほかのクライアントに表示されている写真も投稿と同時に更新されるようにしたいのですが、写真が投稿されてもほかのクライアントの写真が更新されません。
なぜなのでしょうか?

Serverのコード

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-gorp/gorp"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Picture struct {
    Id   int64
    Data []byte
    Name string
    Type string
}

var debug = false

var photodb = "./db/photo.sqlite3"

func main() {
    http.Handle("/layouts/css/", http.StripPrefix("/layouts/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("layouts/css"))))
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    http.Handle("/chat", websocket.Handler(data_handle))
    fmt.Println(":8249")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8249", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.Error())
    }
}

func InitDb() (*gorp.DbMap, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", photodb)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.SqliteDialect{}}
    dbmap.AddTableWithName(Picture{}, "picture").SetKeys(true, "Id")
    err = dbmap.CreateTablesIfNotExists()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return dbmap, nil
}

func insertPic(pic *Picture) {
    dbmap, err := InitDb()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("InitDb error:", err)
    }
    err = dbmap.Insert(pic)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Insert error:", err)
    }
}

func data_receive(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        var b Picture
        if err := websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &b); err != nil {
            if debug {
                fmt.Println(b)
            }
            fmt.Println("Receive error:", err)
        } else {
            insertPic(&b)
            for _, con := range ws_array {
                go func() {
                    err = websocket.JSON.Send(con, b)
                    fmt.Println("con:", con)
                    if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println("Send error:", err)
                    }
                }()
            }
        }
    }
}

var ws_array []*websocket.Conn // *websocket.Connを入れる配列

func data_handle(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    ws_array = append(ws_array, ws)
    data_receive(ws)
}
```

ClientのJavaScript

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8249/chat")
ws.onerror = function (err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
}
var img = document.getElementById("hello");
var f = document.getElementById("file");
var file_reader = new FileReader();
f.onchange = function () {
    var filelist = this.files;
    var file = filelist[0];
    file_reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var b64 = data.slice(data.indexOf(",") + 1);
        var s = {"Name": file.name, "Data": b64, "Type": file.type};
        console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(s));

    }
    file_reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log("Received");
    var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var bytes = atob(obj.Data.replace(/^.*,/, ''));
    var b = new Uint8Array(obj.Data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.Data.length; i++) {
        b[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var blob = new Blob([b.buffer], {type: obj.Type});
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.src = url;

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <title>Websocket json</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="websocket.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
        <img id="hello">
        <script src="websocket_json.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <title>Websocket json</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="websocket.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
        <img id="hello">
        <script src="websocket_json.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 具体的にどのようにうまくいかないのか書いてください。クライアント側のコードも必要です。あとDBに入れるだけで取り出していないようですが意味あるのでしょうか。

Comment: clientのjs, htmlを追加しました。

あるページで写真が投稿されたら、これに接続しているほかのページのimgも投稿されたものに変わるようにしたいと思っています。

DBは保存のためだけにInsertしていて、実際に送るデータはReceiveから直接Sendしています。

Comment: 「うまくいかない」という表現は具体性がありません。サーバーが停止するのか、クライアントがフリーズするのか、何かエラーが出るのか、画像が読み込めないのか、画像が送信できないのか、画像が受信できないのか、受信できるけど表示されないのか、壊れた画像が表示されるのか、データの受信すらできないのか、表示されるけど同時には表示されないのか、一部のクライアントでは表示されるけどほかは表示されないのか etc...　そこを説明しないとどこが問題か分かりません。

Comment: @h2so5 投稿されたらすぐにほかのクライアント全てに表示したいしたいのですが表示されません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブロードキャスト時のループ

```
        for _, con := range ws_array {
            go func() {
                err = websocket.JSON.Send(con, b)
                fmt.Println("con:", con)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Send error:", err)
                }
            }()
        }
```

これを

```
        for _, con := range ws_array {
            con := con
            go func() {
                err = websocket.JSON.Send(con, b)
                fmt.Println("con:", con)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Send error:", err)
                }
            }()
        }
```

にすれば直ると思います。for ループ内で goroutine を使っているので最終のコネクションだけに応答が飛んでしまっているのだと思います。

Comment: 手元で動いた物を置いておきます。 https://gist.github.com/mattn/e842cad6cc3b1672ce89